# Port Forwarding Rule Semantics

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

Note: This is ***not*** a "how do I fix this" question. I want to understand what the two different types of rules in question mean.

TL;DR: What's the difference between

```
TCP 5193 -> 5193
```

and

```
TCP Any  -> 5193
```

and what do they each actually mean?

Long version:

I have an application (Transmission bittorrent client) running on kubuntu 16.04 Linux (notebook) which needs to receive information on a particular port (5193 - but I can select any other unused port).

To make this work, I went into my (FiOS Actiontec) gateway and told it to forward the port one way and it didn't work. I changed it to another way and it did work.

I don't want to use precise technical jargon here because I'll almost undoubtedly get it wrong. Instead, I am including a screenshot from my router which shows two similar rules - not the exact ones in question - where the first one is defined the way that doesn't work and the second one is defined the way that does work.

What I want to know is what do the two rules "mean" and why might one work while the other does not.

I do not have a firewall running and have not configured any other routing related things. I just have the defaults that come with kubuntu.

[image: Two similar rules - one of each type]

These two rules were just close together to make the screenshot smaller. The real one that I'm asking about has the correct port number and IP address in it.

Edit:

Port Forwarding Dialog

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of the form where you set these values?

Comment: @DanielB - The screenshot is from that form. I didn't want to include the whole thing partly because it might reveal things useful to a  cracker, but mainly because it might distract from the actual question which is more about how things work than the actual details of my particular setup.

Comment: No, the screenshot shows the already added rules. I’d like to see a screenshot of the editor where you enter the port numbers, IP addresses and whatnot. The editor may contain important labels that are not visible in the condensed list view.

Comment: @DanielB - Added the requested screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCP Any  -> 5193` means that anyone that wants to connect to port 5193 will be able to do so without any other restrictions.

`TCP 5193 -> 5193` means only who uses port 5193 as a source port will be able to connect to your destination 5193 port.

So if an application uses source port 5193 to connect to the destination on 5193 it will work in both cases, but if it uses a random source port (any other than 5193) it will work only with `any -> 5193` rule.

Comment: Apparently, there's more here that I don't understand. If another BitTorrent client wants to start communicating with my client, I think they have to send that message to my destination port (5193). Does that message also show a source port it was sent from? If that's the case, then it makes sense why my first rule doesn't work because it's unlikely that they would use the same port as the one I selected. But, why is there a  source port at all?  Is that the port I have to use to respond back to them to tell them what data I want or that I received it correctly?

Comment: Maybe this is just a case where the router has to be able to handle situations which are more complex than this one, so it has options that don't really apply here, but can cause the connection to be blocked if set incorrectly.

Comment: Part of what confuses me is that torrents still work when there is no available open port. The *big* difference is that there are no "incoming" connections. It appears as if my client has to find and invite all the peers itself. This seems to imply that clients can still talk to each other without the open port. Just one important type of communication is blocked.

Comment: @Joe If there was no source port, how would you send a response to them? And how would their OS know which program to deliver that response to? Imagine if three programs on my computer are all communicating with www.google.com and they're all connecting to port 80. Without different source ports, how would my computer tell which responses go with which connections and thus to which programs?